# Phrase with keywords search in solr

Tags: python, solr

I want to create a solr query that searches a text field for keywords. This query does not seems to be working:

```
display_string:\+foo\+bar
```

It returns values with bar only. Also, using `{!complexphrase}` in front of the query gives me the following error:

> Unknown query parser 'complexphrase'

Comment: What should the value contain? "foo AND bar", "foo OR bar" or "foo XOR bar"?

Comment: "foo AND bar", adding a `+` in front of the keywords means they would be included, right?

Comment: try this: display_string:(+foo AND +bar)

Comment: It is working without the AND! I was not using brackets!